# when a PhD position is re-posted after I had an interview

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I had a PhD interview and they said this decision will be made by the end of this week.
I haven't received any email from them yet.

However, I saw a new advertisement about the same position as I applied a few days ago.

Does this mean I am rejected?
Should I send an email to an administers to ask if I had failed?

Comment: No, don't send email. Just live your life as if you were rejected (eg apply for other jobs as if you didn't get this one). Maybe you get a positive answer from them.

Comment: Are you sure it's indeed the same position? Possibly they offer multiple positions from the same funding source. Also, are you sure it's a new ad (changed submission deadline etc.)? Possibly the ad was posted late on some particular distribution channel.

Comment: It is not the end of the werk yet so they can still advertise and you wait for their response.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper: I think closely inspecting the details of the new position only makes one nervous and opens the mind for furthee negative theories, thus I wouldn't recommend it. Even if it is hard, try to stay calm and not to think about it right now.

Comment: @user111388 Might be a personality thing. Not knowing would make me more nervous than knowing and having clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It could have a lot of reason why a position is reposted. Computer mistake, additional position, confusion with another position, people not talking properly to each other, fraud, rejection, ...
Don't do anything at least until the end of this week (which is near)! Do not look at their homepages if this makes you nervous.

In the meantime, live your life as if you did not get this position. Apply for other jobs etc.
If you really want to get a definite answer from them and they do not call you, I would give it two more weeks (could vary by locale) until you call them. Do ask for feedback and do not call your rejection a "failure". In most interviews, people do not fail (except there is a special test) but it comes out that they don't fit the position well enough because of other interests.